# URL Shortning Code to short actually Page

Tags: php, url

I am trying to use for my own Website this Script https://github.com/briancray/PHP-URL-Shortener. On the Readme it tells this here

To programmatically shorten URLs with PHP use the following code:

```
$shortenedurl = file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/shorten.php?longurl=' . urlencode('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

If i add this Code to any Page of my Website it should shorten the actually Sites Link. But it will not show me the Link and Shorten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing

```
$shortenedurl = file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/shorten.php?longurl=' . urlencode('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

would only shorten it and save it as a variable. To display it, you will need to display the contents of the variable using [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). Try this:

```
$shortenedurl = file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/shorten.php?longurl=' . urlencode('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
echo $shortenedurl;
```

Comment: Could you tell me maybe too how i can add API Key into this Script?

Comment: @karabey: I am not sure what you mean. Looking at the [source code](http://briancray.com/posts/free-php-url-shortener-script/), there is no mention of an API key.